# IPFS js - is it possible to know what peers are holding what data?

Tags: ipfs

I have this snippet here from  https://js.ipfs.io/:

```
const node = await IPFS.create()

const stream = node.cat('QmPChd2hVbrJ6bfo3WBcTW4iZnpHm8TEzWkLHmLpXhF68A')
let data = ''

for await (const chunk of stream) {
  // chunks of data are returned as a Buffer, convert it back to a string
  data += chunk.toString()
}

console.log(data)
```

It prints fine and I can the data.

My questions:

- Where exactly is this data corresponding to the hash stored? Is it possible to know what peers are storing this data?
- What happens if I want to change the data? Do I have to generate a new hash every time?

Answer (score 0):

If your node has a copy of the data, it'll be stored in your local [repo](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/REPO.md).

If it does not, it'll use [bitswap](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/BITSWAP.md) to try to fetch it from connected peers.

You can find out which peers have the data by querying the DHT using [ipfs.dht.findProvs](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/DHT.md#ipfsdhtfindprovscid-options).

The 'QmPCh..' string is a [content identifier](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/content-addressing/) so if the data changes, so will the hash.